# single dimensional array print through foreach loop

Tags: arrays, static-methods

How I can print the elements of single dimensional array via foreach loop method

```
public class SingleArrayPrac {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

        // for(int row : array)  This way i can print array but i want to print through method, How?
        // System.out.println(row);
        for (int print : array) {
            printRow(print);
        }
    }

    public static void printRow(int row) {
        for (int print : row) { // Error at Row
            System.out.println(print);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in the printRow method row is an integer, how would you want to iterate over an integer? You just need to print the parameter.

Comment: The `row` variable in your `printRow` method already contains the array element. So you just need to print `row` in `printRow` with `println`,

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies where you declare your printRow method. You pass a int where you should pass a int[] array. This causes the error because you are trying over a variable that is not a collection of data. It should like so:

```
public static void printRow(int[] row) {

    for (int print : row) { 
        System.out.println(print);
    }
}
```

Now when you want to print your array just call printRow(array) where array is an int[].

Answer (score 0):

Read the comments in the below code for explanation:

```
public class SingleArrayPrac {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    /*
    Here print variable will hold the next array element in next iteration. 
    i.e in first iteration, print = 1, in second iteration print = 2 and so on
    */
        for (int print : array) {  
            //You pass that element to printRow
            printRow(print);
        }
    }

    public static void printRow(int row) {
        //This will print the array element received.
        System.out.println(print);
    }
}
```

The other solution can be:

```
public class SingleArrayPrac {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

        printRow(array); //Here you pass the whole array to printRow
    }

    public static void printRow(int[] row) {
        /*
          The array is received in row variable and than each element of the array is printed.
        */
        for (int print : row) { 
            System.out.println(print);
        }
    }
}
```